# Is there way to add array of objectid and other field in mongodb schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to create a schema , with multiple object id with each object id containing a Number.

Like for this data,

`[ "user": [["collection1",1], ["collection2", 3], ["collection4": 4]`

where `user` is a user object id, and `collection1, collection2 ....` are collection object id, and other are just number.

```
const derivedSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref: "User"},
    collections: {type: [ObjectId], ref="collection"}],
);
```

I tried to change like put `[ObjectId, Number]` if it would look like my data

and tried to save as like this

```
let collected = new derivedSchema({
        "user": uid,
        "collections": [cid, 12],
      })
      collected.save()
```

where cid is collectionid, uid is userid , 12 number, i passed through in for loop.

But it is not working.
Is there any way to solve this ?
Thank you

At end result i should show like

```
[
   "user1": { ["col1",1], ["col2", 5]},
   "user2": { ["col1",55], ["col2", 35]},
]
```

Any idea would be really helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const derivedSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
           type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "User"
    },
    collections:{
        type:[Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref:"collection"
    }
);
```

Comment: Hello thank you this solves my problem. If i want to add like collection and also number to that specific collection how can i add number too .on that specific collections field. for eg like [userid, [collectionid1, number1], [collectionid2, number5], [collectionid3,number2]]